# dispatch_apply GCD for 'for loop'

Tags: c++, ios, for-loop, parallel-processing, grand-central-dispatch

Can somebody help me by formatting the following type of for loop to the GCD `dispatch_apply` query?

```
for (y = a; y + b < h - c; y += d)
{
    // body independent of y
    *m++ = *n++ - *p++; 
}
```

where `*m`, `*n` and `*p` are float pointers

The dispatch_apply API has the following description:

```
dispatch_apply(<#size_t iterations#>, <#dispatch_queue_t queue#>, <#^(size_t)block#>)
```

This might be more of a mathematical puzzle, but any help will be great!

Thanks.

**EDIT:** My working is as follows:

```
dispatch_apply((h-c-b-a)/d + 1, someQueue, ^(size_t blkId){
    m[blkId] = n[blkId] - p[blkId];
});
```

Comment: In your variant block will be called one time if `a + b == h - c`. Correctly it should not be called since `y + b < h - c` in `for` is never true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dispatch_apply((h - c - b - a + d - 1)/d, dispatch_main(), ^(blkId) {
    m[blkId] = n[blkId] - p[blkId]
});
```

UPDATE: following should have the same result

```
dispatch_apply(ceil((double)(h - c - b - a) / d ), dispatch_main(), ^(blkId) {
    m[blkId] = n[blkId] - p[blkId]
});
```

in first variant I have used that `(int)ceil( x / y ) == (int)( x + y - 1 / y )`

Comment: Why do you have a '-1' there?

Comment: `(int)((h - c - b - a + d - 1)/d)` is the same as `ceil((double)(h - c - b - a) / d )`